# form_tag for search model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search controller which is to be used to search over a separate model called house.  The house model has a restful setup.  I want the results listed on the index action of the search controller.  The form_tag url is giving me some problems.  What is the correct path for this?

Below is the search form (search/form):

```
 <% form_tag index_search do -%>
  <p>
<%= collection_select(:house, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
</p>
<p>
 <strong>price</strong><br />

<%= text_field_tag :min_price, params[:min_price], :size => 3 %>
<%= text_field_tag :max_price, params[:max_price], :size => 4 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `rake routes`, it'll show all the named paths available to you.

I do `rake routes | grep <something>` pretty much daily.

You probably want `searches_path()` for what you're thinking.

Comment: Well I have houses as a resource.  The search route is simply the default made by the controller.

Comment: Yep.  So, `searches_path` would go to searches_controller:index().  Use `form_tag searches_path do ...`